# Email list of tuples as body - Python

Tags: python, list, email, tuples

I am working with a list that consists of servers (Name, IP) tuples.  I am testing each server for connectivity using ping.  If the ping fails, it's added to a list called `issues`.  I am attempting to email this list of failures to myself, given there are any.  I'm not sure what I've got wrong, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Scripts/serverconnection.py", line 26, in <module>
    msg['SUBJECT'] = "Server Disconnect Notice"
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

The code generating the error is below

```
if len(issues) > 0 :
    body = '\n'.join('%s, %s' % server for server in issues)
    msg = body
    msg['SUBJECT'] = "Server Disconnect Notice"
    msg['FROM'] = "Alli Deacon"
    msg['TO'] = 'allid@atlanticpkg.com'
    msg.attach(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because **msg** is a **str**, so you can't do `msg['SUBJECT']` as in dict

Try the following:

```
msg = dict()
msg['SUBJECT'] = "Server Disconnect Notice"
msg['FROM'] = "Alli Deacon"
msg['TO'] = 'allid@atlanticpkg.com'
msg.send() # i don't know what module for e-mails you use
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, you helped me realize what I was missing.  I needed to utilize the MIMEText functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the following import:

`from email.MIMEText import MIMEText`

And then updated my code with the following:

`msg = MIMEText(body)`

After I updated with these additions, the code worked fine.